# Failed to load a .bin.gz pre trained words2vecx

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I'm trying to load the pre-trained words2vecs which I've found here (https://github.com/mmihaltz/word2vec-GoogleNews-vectors)
I used the following command:

```
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('word2vec.bin.gz', binary=False)
```

### And it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/deeplearning/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 193, in 
 load_word2vec_format
    header = utils.to_unicode(fin.readline(), encoding=encoding)
  File "/home/deeplearning/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 374, 
in readline
    return self._buffer.readline(size)
  File "/home/deeplearning/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/_compression.py", 
line 68, in readinto
    data = self.read(len(byte_view))
  File "/home/deeplearning/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 463, 
in read
    if not self._read_gzip_header():
  File "/home/deeplearning/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 411, 
in _read_gzip_header
    raise OSError('Not a gzipped file (%r)' % magic)
OSError: Not a gzipped file (b've')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the error says, "Not a gzipped file", maybe the file has been inadvertently uncompressed, but still has the misleading `.gzip` extension? (Try renaming without `.gzip`, an loading that file.)

Because the filename includes `.bin`, it is likely a 'binary' style word2vec format. So the optional parameter may need to be `binary=True`.

The filename you're using, `word2vec.bin.gz`, does not match the filename at the link you provided, `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz`. This suggests other changes may have occurred that could cause problems.

The error also reports a 'magic number' (indicative prefix) from the file, `b've'`, that looks like a bit of plain text, rather than the beginning of a real gzip file. You might want to look at the first few lines of the problem file, via something like `head word2vec.bin.gz`, to see if there are other indications of what it is (other than what you expect it to be).

Answer (score 0):

for example, I chouse this file called "GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz"

```
curl -o - https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz | gunzip > ./GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin
```

**Explanation:**

- represents the standard output. The standard output is what gets redirected by piping with |.
  From [man curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> Specifying the output as '-' (a single dash) will force the output to
> be done to stdout.

So for your situation, do the same for your file

for more information see the original solution:

[issue and solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1235085/how-to-use-gzip-or-gunzip-in-a-pipeline-with-curl-for-binary-gz-files)