# OSError: Not a gzipped file (b've') python

Tags: python, word2vec, gensim

I have the following code and I made sure its extension and name are correct. However, I still get the error outputted as seen below.

I did see another person asked a similar question here on Stack Overflow, and read the answer but it did not help me.

[Failed to load a .bin.gz pre trained words2vecx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045881/failed-to-load-a-bin-gz-pre-trained-words2vecx)

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Input:

```
import gensim
word2vec_path = "GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz"
word2vec = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(word2vec_path, binary=True)
```

Output:

```
OSError: Not a gzipped file (b've')
```

Comment: If you're on a UNIX-like system, try running `file GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz` at the command line. Guessing it's not actually a gzipped file. Changing the extension doesn't magically make it compressed, you actually need to compress it.

Comment: It *is* actually a gzipped file. `b've'` does not look anything like a regular gzip header magic sig, but it can still extract the 1.5Gb source into a single 3.5Gb data file (this file contains plain text entries and lots of floating point numbers). So, don't use a Python program to unpack it (why would you need a program?), just do so manually on the command line.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I am using Windows 7

Comment: If `gunzip GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz` creates a plain-text file, you would not want to be specifying `binary=True`. (That's only if it's the word2vec `binary` format.) But you should probably re-fetch the file from a known source, being careful to not change its name at any step, and that it is not truncated at any step. Also maybe your Windows7/Python is only 32-bit and thus has issues handling >2GB files? (If at all possible, best to use a Linux/UNIX system where this stack of tools is most tested/documented.)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the file you've downloaded is not a gzip file. If you check the size of the file it maybe in KBs (that is what happened with me, when I downloaded it from [this Github link](https://github.com/mmihaltz/word2vec-GoogleNews-vectors) because it needed git-lfs)

Here is an alternate solution to resolve this issue:

Download the model using the below command on your terminal:

```
wget -c "https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz"
```

Then, load the model as you would using gensim:

```
from gensim import models

w = models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(
    'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
```

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: The link seems to be not valid. I get `ERROR 404: Not Found.`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```py
import tensorflow
word2vec_path = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz'
word2vec = models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(word2vec_path, binary=True)
```